# Using Ruby Gem for Twitter to get search results of a Hashtag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems

I am trying to use this [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to connect with Twitter and return a list of all tweets that have a particular hashtag. As of right now, I have been able to connect to the API and return data, so I know that the connection is working. I have read through the documentation and am just not understanding how to implement what I am seeing. I am really new to connecting and utilizing APIs and some clarification would really be appreciated. Here is the code that I have so far.

Gemfile

```
#####################
### My Added Gems ###
#####################

# Define Ruby Version
ruby "2.5.0"

# Social Connections
gem 'twitter'

# ENV Variables
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<h1>Tweets</h1>
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <%= tweet.full_text %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  require 'twitter'

  def home
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV.fetch("YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY")
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV.fetch("YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET")
      config.access_token        = ENV.fetch("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN")
      config.access_token_secret = ENV.fetch("YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET")
    end

    @tweets = client.user_timeline('trendingfaith', count: 20)

  end
end
```

This prints out a list of the tweets for the user @TrendingFaith.

What I tried to get it to print out all tweets with the hashtag #TrendingFaith:

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  require 'twitter'

  def home
    tweets = Twitter::REST::Search.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV.fetch("YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY")
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV.fetch("YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET")
      config.access_token        = ENV.fetch("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN")
      config.access_token_secret = ENV.fetch("YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET")
    end
    @tweets = tweets.search(q, options = {:hash => 'trendingfaith'}) ⇒ Twitter::SearchResults

  end
end
```

Got the following error: `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end`

I tried reading through [this doc on the Twitter Gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter) and the [Twitter API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/standard.html). I just can't understand it at this time to know how to implement it. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATED: Working Code after receiving an Answer**

Per the answer by @SimonFranzen, the code that I was missing was `client.search('#SpecificTag')` syntax to search for a specific hashtag.

Here is what my code now looks like:

controllers/pages_controllers.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  require 'twitter'

  def home
    tweets = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV.fetch("YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY")
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV.fetch("YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET")
      config.access_token        = ENV.fetch("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN")
      config.access_token_secret = ENV.fetch("YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET")
    end
    @tweets = tweets.search('#TrendingFaith')
  end
end
```

I ran [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) on this and was able to see the data that came back from Twitter with this search. (See hash data below) and was thus able to update my view like this:

views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<h1>TrendingFaith.org - Coming Soon</h1>
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  User @<%= tweet.user.screen_name %> said: "<%= tweet.text %>" on <%= tweet.created_at.strftime('%-m/%d/%Y') %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

This was able to pull the Twitter user's name, the text of the tweet and when they tweeted it. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Twitter hash that was returned to me, placed here for others that may want to know. Also, you can [see it here in their documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html) at the bottom of the page.

```
{
  :created_at=>"Sun Mar 04 18:20:42 +0000 2018", 
  :id=>970363418858332160, 
  :id_str=>"970363418858332160", 
  :text=>"A place where you can find things trending in the Christian faith. Questions and stories. #TrendingFaith", 
  :truncated=>false, 
  :entities=>
    {
      :hashtags=>[{
        :text=>"TrendingFaith", 
        :indices=>[90, 104]
      }], 
      :symbols=>[], 
      :user_mentions=>[], 
      :urls=>[]
    }, 
  :metadata=>
    {
      :iso_language_code=>"en", 
      :result_type=>"recent"
    }, 
  :source=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
  :in_reply_to_status_id=>nil, 
  :in_reply_to_status_id_str=>nil, 
  :in_reply_to_user_id=>nil, 
  :in_reply_to_user_id_str=>nil, 
  :in_reply_to_screen_name=>nil, 
  :user=>
    {
      :id=>970155879180873733, 
      :id_str=>"970155879180873733", 
      :name=>"Trending Faith", 
      :screen_name=>"TrendingFaith", 
      :location=>"", 
      :description=>"", 
      :url=>#Twitter URL Shortener (Had to remove for Stackoverflow),  
      :entities=>
        {
          :url=>
            {
              :urls=>[
                {
                  :url=>#Twitter URL Shortener (Had to remove for Stackoverflow), 
                  :expanded_url=>"http://trendingfaith.org", 
                  :display_url=>"trendingfaith.org", 
                  :indices=>[0, 23]
                }
              ]
            }, 
          :description=>
            {
              :urls=>[]
            }
        }, 
      :protected=>false, 
      :followers_count=>0, 
      :friends_count=>3, 
      :listed_count=>0, 
      :created_at=>"Sun Mar 04 04:36:00 +0000 2018", 
      :favourites_count=>0, 
      :utc_offset=>nil, 
      :time_zone=>nil, 
      :geo_enabled=>false, 
      :verified=>false, 
      :statuses_count=>1, 
      :lang=>"en", 
      :contributors_enabled=>false, 
      :is_translator=>false, 
      :is_translation_enabled=>false, 
      :profile_background_color=>"F5F8FA", 
      :profile_background_image_url=>nil, 
      :profile_background_image_url_https=>nil, 
      :profile_background_tile=>false, 
      :profile_image_url=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png", 
      :profile_image_url_https=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png", 
      :profile_link_color=>"1DA1F2", 
      :profile_sidebar_border_color=>"C0DEED", 
      :profile_sidebar_fill_color=>"DDEEF6", 
      :profile_text_color=>"333333", 
      :profile_use_background_image=>true, 
      :has_extended_profile=>false, 
      :default_profile=>true, 
      :default_profile_image=>true, 
      :following=>false, 
      :follow_request_sent=>false, 
      :notifications=>false, 
      :translator_type=>"none"
    }, 
  :geo=>nil, 
  :coordinates=>nil, 
  :place=>nil, 
  :contributors=>nil, 
  :is_quote_status=>false, 
  :retweet_count=>0, 
  :favorite_count=>0, 
  :favorited=>false, 
  :retweeted=>false, 
  :lang=>"en"
}
```

**New Question**

Now to figure out why only one tweet is coming back as there are hundreds with the hashtag that I am searching for, but only one for me. I checked by searching the hashtag '#HelloWorld' and it came back with many. So, it isn't just searching my tweets. I am guessing that all of the others with the hashtag I am looking for may be private tweets unable to be pulled except through Twitter? Or is this another issue with my code? If this is an unrelated issue to my original question, I can create a new question and ask.

**FINAL UPDATE: Answer to last question**

The reason that only my tweet is being pulled for the hashtag 'TrendingFaith' but I get a lot more tweets when pulling the hashtag 'HelloWorld' is because only my tweet was made within the past week with '#TrendingFaith'. The Standard Twitter API search only pulls the past 7-days of tweets. You have to have a Premium or Enterprise level account to search for 30-day or full archived posts. Their Premium level is currently (as of 3/4/2018) in beta and taking requests to be on their waitlist.

[Link to Twitter Page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/standard.html)

Comment: Do you have this weird arrow also in your sourcecode ? ⇒ Twitter::SearchResults

Comment: Outcomment your foreach in the view and replace it with `<%= @twitter.inspect %>` that you know what you are getting from the server

Comment: This is also a good starting point for twitter-api for rails https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-wrapper-for-twitter-search-api and did you check out this exmaple for your gem ? https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Search.md#search

Comment: @SimonFranzen, I got that arrow syntax from http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search

And using the `inspect` I get the Twitter ID: `#<Twitter::Tweet id=970363418858332160> `

I will check out those links. Thank you.

Comment: remove the arrow and the stuff after

Comment: @SimonFranzen, using the first link is old as the gem has a new name `gem 'dancroak-twitter-search'`. And utilizing that on their github page pulls an error that it looks like that gem is utilizing an old API for Twitter.  

https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-search

Comment: @SimonFranzen I receive this error now  `undefined method 'new' for Twitter::REST::Search:Module`

Comment: I tried changing the first block statement to this `tweets = Twitter::SearchResults.new do |config|` and get the following error: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

Comment: Beware of the syntax. You should read a bit about ruby blocks and Hash. I added an answer which is code of production running systems and its working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)

```
gem install twitter
```

or include it in your Gemfile

Create Twitter App, get auth codes

Init API

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

Make a request "Tweets for user"

```
// get from user
tweets = client.user_timeline('rubyinside', count: 20)
tweets.each { |tweet| puts tweet.full_text }
```

Make a request "Search by hashtag"

```
client.search('#searchHash').take(3).each do |tweet|
  puts tweet.inspect
end
```

Checkout this to buildup your query: https://www.hitchhq.com/twitter/activities/592c37f4da4746638900618e
or https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

Comment: The syntax that I was needing is in your last code section. I was missing the `client.search('#SpecificTag')`. Thank you. I will mark this as the answer and then update my question with my new code that works.

Comment: I updated my question with a continued question. Maybe it is related to my original post. If not, I can create a new question and ask it there.